# How can you chose ScrollViews to hide created in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I create ScrollViews with buttons on them  with following code.
What I want to do is hiding or unhiding ScrollViews but how?

```
var body: some View {
    
   
    
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat(buttonNames.count)
    
    
    ZStack {
        ForEach(0..<2, id: \.self) {
            
            scrollIndex in
            
            
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    
                    
                    
                    LazyHStack {
                        ForEach(0..<buttonNames.count, id: \.self) {
                            index in
                            
                            
                            Button(action:
                                    {
                                
                                
                                touchedButton = scrollIndex * 10 + index
                                buttonTouched()
                                
                            }
                            ){
                                //touchedButton = index
                                Text(buttonNames[scrollIndex][index])
                                
                                
                            }
                            .frame(width: width)
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .tag(scrollIndex)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 45, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    
                    
                   
                    
                }
                

                .position(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 45)
               
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The goal is not clear, hiding scroll view will hide all its content. Could you elaborate more of what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am creating several horizontal scrollviews with buttons. When I hide one I will unhide an other one with different buttons with different functions.

Comment: Put scroll view into condition and manage condition by view model property via buttons.